# JavaScript: how to use async FileReader in sync code?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, request, multipartform-data

I have following code that works syncronously. Basically it accept html form and parse it's elements into url string.

```
SmFaq.DataForm = function (f) { // f is HTML form
    var P = new Array();

    /* parsing array */

    var params = P.join("&");
    return params;
}
```

It worked nice, but now i need to add `input type="file"`. I made request based on this article: [Sending forms with JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript) (**Dealing with binary data**) and everything works fine except loading binary data in request body. My function return string before file was readed.

Task: i need to read and add binary data to request body string and then *return* this string. Is it possible? I don't care if GUI will freeze for loading time.

Here's my code:

```
SmFaq.DataForm = function (f) { 

    var name = f.querySelector('#created_by'); 
    var email = f.querySelector('#created_by_email'); 
    var question = f.querySelector('#question'); 
    var file = { 
        dom: f.querySelector('#file'), 
        binary: null 
    }; 

    var reader = new FileReader(); // to read binary data 


    if (file.dom.files[0]) { 
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file.dom.files[0]); 
    } 

    file.dom.addEventListener('change', function() { 
    if (reader.readyState === FileReader.LOADING) { 
        reader.abort(); 
    } 

        reader.readAsBinaryString(file.dom.files[0]); 
    }); 

    reader.addEventListener('loadend', function() { 
        file.binary = reader.result; 
        console.log('Binary data loaded!'); 
    }); 

    return sendData(); 

    function sendData() { 

        if (!file.binary && file.dom.files.length > 0) { 
            setTimeout(sendData, 2000); 
            return; 
        } 


        var boundary = "1234567890"; 

        var data = ''; 

        data += '--' + boundary + '\r\n'; 
        data += 'content-disposition: form-data; ' 
        + 'name="' + file.dom.name + '";' 
        + 'filename="' + file.dom.files[0].name + '"\r\n'; 
        data += 'Content-Type: ' + file.dom.files[0].type + '\r\n'; 
        data += '\r\n';
        data += file.binary + '\r\n';

        data += '--' + boundary + '\r\n'; 
        data += 'content-disposition: form-data; name="' + name.name + '"\r\n'; 
        data += '\r\n'; 
        data += name.value + '\r\n'; 

        data += '--' + boundary + '\r\n';
        data += 'content-disposition: form-data; name="' + email.name + '"\r\n'; 
        data += '\r\n'; 
        data += email.value + '\r\n'; 

        data += '--' + boundary + '\r\n';
        data += 'content-disposition: form-data; name="' + question.name + '"\r\n'; 
        data += '\r\n'; 
        data += question.value + '\r\n'; 
        data += '--' + boundary + '--'; 
        data += '\r\n'; 

        return data; 
    }
}
```

I do not know this async things so it sure not working as expected.

Plese do not use ES7 features, i work with legacy code and have no possibility to use Babel.

Comment: "Is it possible?" — No.

Comment: Use formdata instead! if you need a polyfill for that use [mine](https://github.com/jimmywarting/FormData). there is a minified version that you can just include

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do it synchronously. Here is how to do it asynchronously :

```js
var SmFaq = {};

SmFaq.DataForm = function(f, callback) {
  var name = f.querySelector('#created_by'),
    file = f.querySelector('#file'),
    data = '',
    reader = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener('loadend', function() {
    console.log('Here are binary datas !');
    data += reader.result;

    callback(data);
  });

  data += 'Created by ';
  data += name.value;
  data += '\n';

  if (file.files[0]) {
    data += file.files[0].name;
    data += '\n';
    data += ' ... ';
    data += '\n';

    console.log('Waiting for binary datas...');
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file.files[0]);
  } else {
    callback(data);
  }
}

function handleData(data) {
  // Do whatever you want to do with data
  console.log(data);
}

document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  SmFaq.DataForm(this, handleData);
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" id="created_by" placeholder="Who Am I ?" /><br />
  <input type="file" id="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Change the way `DataForm` is called to add a callback to it, and call the `callback` function when you have all your datas. Then you handle those datas inside the callback function, `handleData` in my example.